# bug in lightning screen , white screen after click on tab

Tags: lightning, list-view, session

hey when i click on the tab of custom object , sometime i receive a blank page . the page is a standard listview without any custom action from us .
the problem seem to come from multiple network access .
i check a cookie session is always created and removed in a infinite loop ...

Here a video that show the problem :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YQl78AZOmdFbtcvpZLaYyHPxdxHyJet8/view?usp=sharing

thanks for help

Comment: Does this screen include any custom LWCs? Have you considered or tried debugging the executed JavaScript to find out whether this looping is caused by one of your LWCs?

Comment: no it's a standard list view , can't add custom LWC componant .

Comment: Do you have any actions? It would be good if you could [edit] your question to provide more context because otherwise it will be pretty difficult for the community to help you. I recommend you try to look see what is happening in the JavaScript and on the Network (use the browser's inspector if you can) and verify whether this looping is to do with repeated network access or just within the JavaScript. I suggest you also add detail on what the page content is (you mentioned list view only in comments) and the situation where you get the blank page (e.g. in mobile app/browser).

Comment: i finnaly resolve the probleme , the problem comes in a VF pages if you want to add one of the following method :UserInfo.UITheme() 
UserInfo.UIThemeDisplayed()  this cause some bug to restart the page without end ...

Comment: Please add this as a complete answer so others will properly benefit from your learning.

Comment: Obviously, we would need you to edit the question to add more detail first.